# InputSelect not updating value in CRUD operations

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am working on a blazor webassembly project which has a form. When performing edit operation the values loads up correctly in all fields including dropdown i.e `InputSelect`. But when changed the value of `InputSelect` the value does not get updated in Database and is not reflected in list of records. Other controls like textfield and date values does get updated . I have posted the code which is a razor component and from the razor component api call is made. Below is the code....Can u help me out with a solution. The problem is with SurfingQuota and BandwidthPolicy InputSelect control

```
@page "/packages/add"
@page "/packages/edit/{packageId:int}"
@inject HttpClient _httpClient
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<PageTitle>Package</PageTitle>

@if (packageId == 0)
{
    <h3>Create Package</h3>
}
else
{
    <h3>Edit Package</h3>
}
<hr />
<EditForm Model="package" OnValidSubmit="AddOrUpdatePackage">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
    <div class="row g-3 mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="PackageName" class="form-label">Package Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind-value="package.PackageName" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>package.PackageName)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row g-3 mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="PackageType" class="form-label">Package Type</label>
            <select name="PackageType" id="PackageType" @bind="package.PackageType" class="form-select">
                <option value="" disabled selected>select package type</option>
                <option value="Registration">Registration</option>
                <option value="Renewal">Renewal</option>
            </select>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>package.PackageType)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row g-3 mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="ConnectionType" class="form-label">Connection Type</label>
            <InputSelect @bind-Value="package.ConnectionType" class="form-select">
                <option selected disabled value="">select connection type</option>
                <option value="User">User</option>
                <option value="Leased Line">Leased Line</option>
            </InputSelect>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>package.ConnectionType)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row g-3 mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="Price" class="form-label">Price</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" @bind-value="package.Price" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>package.Price)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row g-3 mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="Timeout" class="form-label">Timeout (in minutes)</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" @bind-value="package.Timeout" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>package.Timeout)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row g-3 mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="SurfingQuotaPolicy" class="form-label">Surfing Quota Policy</label>
            <InputSelect class="form-control" @bind-Value="package.SurfingQuotaId">

                @foreach (var surfingQuota in surfingPolicies)
                {
                    <option value="@surfingQuota.SurfingQuotaId">@surfingQuota.SurfingPolicyName</option>
                }

            </InputSelect>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>package.SurfingQuotaPolicy)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row g-3 mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="BandwidthPolicy" class="form-label">Bandwidth Policy</label>
            <InputSelect class="form-select" @bind-Value="package.BandwidthPolicyId">

                @foreach (var bandwidthPolicy in bandwidthPolicies)
                {
                    <option value="@bandwidthPolicy.BandwidthPolicyId">@bandwidthPolicy.BandwidthPolicyName</option>
                }

            </InputSelect>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>package.SurfingQuotaPolicy)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</EditForm>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public int packageId { get; set; }

    private List<SurfingQuota> surfingPolicies { get; set; } = new List<SurfingQuota>();
    private List<BandwidthPolicy> bandwidthPolicies { get; set; } = new List<BandwidthPolicy>();


    Package package = new Package();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        surfingPolicies = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<SurfingQuota>>("api/surfingquota");
        bandwidthPolicies = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<BandwidthPolicy>>("api/bandwidthpolicy");
    }
    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (packageId != 0)
        {
            package = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Package>($"api/package/{packageId}");
        }

    }

    async void AddOrUpdatePackage()
    {
        if (package.PackageId != 0)
        {
            var result = await _httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync("api/package", package);

        }
        else
        {
            await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/package", package);

        }
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/packages");
    }


}
```

I tried using select control but its the same prb

Comment: What does `package` look like?  Specifically the data types of the properties bound to the select controls.

Comment: Package is a string type with only 2 options. The problem is with surfingquota and bandwidthpolicy InputSelect controls and SurfingQuota and BandwidthPolicy are foreign keys

Comment: Are you able to add the structure of the "package" type? Does the type have properties for surfingQuotaId and bandwidthPolicyId? One last question, since it appears you are handling both creation of a model and updating a model, does it work as expected on either of the scenarios?

Comment: I works for creation of the model and for updation except inputselect all works

Answer (score 0):

Your initial problem is here.  This gets `package` every time the component renders.  That's every time you make a change in an input control or click a button, overwriting the new value.

```cs
    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (packageId != 0)
        {
            package = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Package>($"api/package/{packageId}");
        }

    }
```

Normally this code would be in `OnIInitializedAsync`, but if you need it in `OnParametersSetAsync` then you need to do something like this:

```cs
    private int _currentPackageId;

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (packageId != 0 && _currentPackageId != packageId)
        {
            package = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Package>($"api/package/{packageId}");
           _currentPackageId = packageId;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I tried it..but this solution is not working

Comment: @AkshayPatel were you able to figure it out? I'm having the exact same issue as you.